# Errors with MySQL stored function creation ERROR 1064 & 1327

Tags: sql, mysql, function, mysql-error-1064, mysql-error-1327

I am using MySQL v5.1.36 and I am trying to create a stored function using this code.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `modx`.getSTID (x VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    DECLARE y INT;
    SELECT id INTO y
    FROM `modx`.coverage_state
    WHERE `coverage_state`.name = x;
    RETURN y;
    END//
```

When entered into the MySQL Console I get this response.

```
mysql>  DELIMITER //
mysql>  CREATE FUNCTION `modx`.getSTID (x VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    ->          BEGIN
    ->          DECLARE y INT;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at
line 3
mysql>          SELECT id INTO y
    ->          FROM `modx`.coverage_state
    ->          WHERE `coverage_state`.name = x;
ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: y
mysql>          RETURN y;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETUR
N y' at line 1
mysql>          END//
```

From what I can find online my syntax is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the my issues by adding `` around my variables. Here is the code I ended up with.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `modx`.getSTID (x VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    DECLARE `y` INT;
    SELECT id INTO `y`
    FROM `modx`.coverage_state
    WHERE `coverage_state`.name = `x`;
    RETURN `y`;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 7):

When creating a function/procedure from mysql console, the first command should be `DELIMITER //`. Otherwise, it uses default delimiter (`;`),

Comment: Ah, I missed that when I grabbed the information out of the console. I'll fix that in the question.