# Unable to CREATE FUNCTION in MYSQL ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, function

Hi I'm using MySQL to create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION INSERTGROUP(name VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS INT
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE 'idGroup' INT;

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT groupID FROM groupsTable WHERE groupName = 'name'))
THEN INSERT INTO groupsTable (groupName) VALUES ('name');

SELECT groupID INTO 'idGroup' FROM groupsTable WHERE groupName='name';

RETURN 'idGroup';
END//
```

But I get this error when I try to create it:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
''idGroup' INT;

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT groupID FROM serverGroupsTable WHERE gro' at line 5
```

I've been through forums and other questions similar to this one but I can not make it create the function.

What I'm doing wrong? Is the syntax correct? Do I need to add something else?

Ok this is what I've try:

```
CREATE FUNCTION INSERTGROUP(name VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE idGroup INT;

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT groupID FROM groupsTable WHERE groupName = name))
THEN INSERT INTO groupsTable (groupName) VALUES (name);

SELECT groupID INTO idGroup FROM groupsTable WHERE groupName=name;

RETURN idGroup;
END//
```

and

```
CREATE FUNCTION INSERTGROUP(name VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE idGroup INT;

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT groupID FROM groupsTable WHERE groupName = 'name'))
THEN INSERT INTO groupsTable (groupName) VALUES ('name');

SELECT groupID INTO idGroup FROM groupsTable WHERE groupName='name';

RETURN idGroup;
END//
```

and for the last two I got this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'' at line 13
```

Similar to the one above

Also I do `DELIMITER //` to change it from `;`

Comment: update your example with the fixes you implements and still not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the quotes from the declaration

```
DECLARE idGroup INT;
```

and you forgot the delimiter change at the start of the function

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION INSERTGROUP(name VARCHAR(255))
```

and you forgot to end your `if` statement

```
end if;
```

whereever you want it to end

Comment: I've use to have it like that and I got this error without the quotes:
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'' at line 13`

Also I see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406822/errors-with-mysql-stored-function-creation-error-1064-1327

Comment: Should remove them from everywhere that they surround that variable and `name` as well...

Comment: And you need to end your if statement. `end if;`

Comment: I am using the DELIMITER change, but you were right I was missing the `END IF`
Thanks !!